# fast shell find

Tags: linux, shell, find

I have a simple find command that need to go through millions of files on a server and find some with a given suffix. The files are written and deleted over time very frequently. I just wonder if there is a way to make find faster. Using locate is out of question because making database for the locate will be very expensive.

```
find /myDirWithThausandsofDirectories/ -name *.suffix
```

On some servers this commands takes for days!

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: That's about all you can do. find will iterate the directories for you, but going through 'large' directories on a unix system is naturally slow due to how the directory entries are stored.

Comment: break up the problem? `find /myDirWith../dira* -name *.suf & find /myDirWith../dirb* -name *.suf ....&` Also, look at `gnu-parallel` or `xargs -n` Good luck!

Comment: Maybe it is a good case for having something different than millions of files, e.g. GDBM database, or "relational" databases like MySQL or PostGresQL, or noSQL things like mangodb.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the audit subsystem to monitor the creation and deletion of files. Combining this with an initial run of `find` should allow you to create a database of files that you can update in realtime.

Answer (score 3):

Divide and Conquer ? assuming a MP os and processor
spawn multiple `find` commands for each subfolder.

```
for dir in /myDirWithThausandsofDirectories/*
do find "$dir" -name "*.suffix" &
done
```

depending on the number of subdirs you may want to control how many processes (`find` commands) run at a given time. That will be a bit trickier, but doable (ie using a bash shell, keep an array with the pids of the spawned processes `$!` and only allow new ones, depending on the length of the array). 
Also the above doesn't search for files under the root directory, just a quick example of the idea.

If you don't know how to process management is done, time to learn ;) 
[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) is a really good text on the subject. 
[This](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I_want_to_process_a_bunch_of_files_in_parallel.2C_and_when_one_finishes.2C_I_want_to_start_the_next._And_I_want_to_make_sure_there_are_exactly_5_jobs_running_at_a_time.) is what you need actually. But read the whole thing to understand how it works.

Comment: you can also look at things like `nice` and `ionice` to give a greater priority to your script, but I'm not sure if that will make a big difference, and will most probably make the machine unusable for other things.

Comment: I do not know how to control the number of processes!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a simple glob you might be able to use **Bash's recursive globbing**. Example:

```
shopt -s globstar
for path in /etc/**/**.conf
do
    echo "$path"
done
```

Might be faster, since it's using an internal shell capability with much less flexibility than `find`.

If you can't use Bash, but you have a limit to the path depth, you can explicitly list the different depths:

```
for path in /etc/*/*.conf /etc/*/*/*.conf /etc/*/*/*/*.conf
do
    echo "$path"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
find /myDirWithThausandsofDirectories/ -d type maxdepth 1 > /tmp/input
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a files < /tmp/input


do_it() {
   for f; do find $f  -name *.suffix | sed -e s/\.suffix//g ; done
}

# Divide the list into 5 sub-lists.
i=0 n=0 a=() b=() c=() d=() e=()
while ((i < ${#files[*]})); do
    a[n]=${files[i]}
    b[n]=${files[i+1]}
    c[n]=${files[i+2]}
    d[n]=${files[i+3]}
    e[n]=${files[i+4]}
    ((i+=5, n++))
done

# Process the sub-lists in parallel
do_it "${a[@]}" >> /tmp/f.unsorted 2>/tmp/f.err &
do_it "${b[@]}" >> /tmp/f.unsorted 2>/tmp/f.err &
do_it "${c[@]}" >> /tmp/f.unsorted 2>/tmp/f.err &
do_it "${d[@]}" >> /tmp/f.unsorted 2>/tmp/f.err &
do_it "${e[@]}" >> /tmp/f.unsorted 2>/tmp/f.err &
wait
echo Find is Done!
```

The only problem I have with this is some of file names (very small percentage) are out partially. I have no idea what would be the reason though!